# Is there a way to sum up bit positions of an array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Say I have an array like [1,2,3], their correspond bit values are [0001, 0010, 0011]

I want to get an array to remember their bit positions occurrence as ar[4] = {0,0,2,2}.

The only way I can come up is using `bitset`'s `to_string` to transfer value to bit string. then using `stoi` to iterate and add to array. which is quite complex, is there a better way such bit manipulation to solve this?

Comment: I may be dense, but how did you come up with `ar[4] = {0,0,2,2}` given the input is `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: You beat me to the same question...

Comment: It should be number of 1s summed up in each bit position

Comment: @Leni Your explanation is as clear as mud, to be honest.

Comment: Out of `[1,2,3]` -- `1` & `2` don't have bits in both positions?? So how does `ar[4] = {0,0,2,2}` represent `1` & `2`?

Comment: 0001
0010
0011
He has put {0,0,2,2}
No of 1s in each position.

Comment: So all that is being done really is to add those binary numbers as if they're base 10?

Comment: How do you distinguish between `0001 0010 0011` and `0010 0001 0011` or do we assume the array is sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't care about order, I just want to get sum of every bit position. Is there a way for this?

Comment: I assume he just count the number of 1s in each bit position. So the order does not matter actually.

Comment: @JiangFeng -- Look at your input.  Given your description, all you're doing is adding the 1's in each column.  What's the string manipulation supposed to help with?  I don't see a need for it.  `0001 + 0010 + 0011`.  Put those numbers in a column, add the columns just like in elementary school.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It seems that `bitset`'s `to_string` is just to convert the numbers into a binary representation.

Comment: @Tomothy32 -- Still not necessary.  Create an array of 4, and just repeatedly divide to get the binary digit and store in array.  No need for strings.

Comment: Yes, of course. However, you will need to use 8-bit values, (such as `uint8_t` or `unsigned char`). You can only use the bits 0-3, but your minimum storage unit will by 8-bits. Just declare an initialize `int ar[4] = {0};` and use it as a *frequency array*. Write a function something like `void sum (int *a, uint8_t val) { for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { if ((val >> i) & 1) ar[i]++; } }` Call it for each value `1, 2, 3`, the results are in `ar`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So you mean I can only iterate every bit to make it?

Comment: The comment by @DavidC.Rankin and the answer given shows how to iterate and add for column 0, column 1, column 2, etc.  All they are doing is what you would do "by hand" in the example I posted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this. I'm not sure why you needed `to_string` unless I'm missing something from your description.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const int num_bits = sizeof(int) * 8;
    std::vector<int> values = { 1,2,3 };
    int result[num_bits] = {};
    std::bitset<num_bits> bits;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
    {
        bits = values[i];
        for (int bit = 0; bit < num_bits; ++bit)
        {
            result[bit] += bits[bit];
        }
    }
    for (auto num : result)
    {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems I'm too naive. iterate over every bit is necessary!

Comment: It is if you want to capture the sum of each bit **position**. (but with the correct *type* for `num_bits`, it need be no more than `8` (or `4` if you simply declare a constant))

Comment: But note, this algorithm outputs the sum of bits in *reverse* order, e.g. `{2, 2, 0, 0}` instead of `{0, 0, 2, 2}`. You want `const int num_bits = 4;` and then `result[values.size() - bit] += bits[bit];`